# how to save all nested classes using ActiveAndroid?

Tags: android, activeandroid

I am use AciveAndroid library in my project. And i have a quation:

I have some classes

```
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends Model {

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    @SerializedName("uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "userInfo")
    @SerializedName("userInfo")
    private UserInfo userInfo;
...
    }
```

and

```
@Table(name = "UserInfos")
public class UserInfo extends Model {

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "user")
    @SerializedName("user")
    private User user;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "email")
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    private String firstName;
...
}
```

and others classes.

if I want to save the object User i do so:

```
user.save();
```

And get an error.
i do so:

```
userInfo.save();
user.save();
```

and all is well.
but I have many classes that have a other classes. and I can not cause permanent method save(); each class field. 
I expect that when you call `user.save();` saved all nested classes. how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends Model {

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    @SerializedName("uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "userInfo", onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE)
    @SerializedName("userInfo")
    private UserInfo userInfo;
    ...
}
```

Comment: not working, still i have to save each nested class in reverse order.